# Electrically disabling FPGA Regions?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I've been working on a DPR project for quite some time, and I've been wondering if there's a way to electrically disable FPGA regions in order to lower the static power consumption of the chip?

Using Xilinx Vivado, I know I'm able to define pblocks and tell the toolchain not to place any block/route in those, but since the region is still powered I think there will still be some leakage current in here; hence not reducing static power consumption.

Given my understanding of an FPGA architecture, I suppose there may be a way to disable entire clock regions, but I can't tell for sure. Vivado documentations don't seem to point at a way of doing so.

Also, given the hypothesis that this can be done, would ICAP still be functionning and available for DPR purpose? In my opinion, if one would try to reconfigure an FPGA using ICAP on a disabled region, this would just do nothing on the FPGA part, but I fear this would left the ICAP hanging.

Has any of you found a way to do this, or is there a piece of documenation that I'm missing on?

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how to power down a part of a Xilinx FPGA (to reduce its static power), as far as I know.

You can still do a clock gating (to switch off the clock ticking) to reduce a dynamic power, which is usually the bigger portion of the overall power budget.

See for example the BUFGCE primitive in the UltraScale(+) architecture, which can enable/disable a clock feeding a specific region (chapter "BUFGCE Clock Buffers" on the [page 29 of the UG572](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug572-ultrascale-clocking.pdf#page=29) (v1.10.1) "UltraScale Architecture Clocking Resources").